# Validate signed PDF with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, digital-signature

I have PDF file with digital signature. Also i have certificate (public accessed).

How can i check with PHP signature of this PDF file (to be sure that signature is correct)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cryptography and PKI verifying is a complex process. I can suggest you just 3rd party solutions, I do not know any PHP implementation.
We use a JAVA based library, and we call the JAVA classes with JRE.
The libraries are: http://bouncycastle.org/ and http://itextpdf.sourceforge.net/howtosign.html#howtoverify

Comment: No news here for 2020, only Java?